Synonyms in related tags list
There's an old report Tag synonyms shouldn't be listed in Related Tags on the sidebar marked as completed more than 10 years ago.
Now we have faced with the same thing again for synonymized but not merged tags.
For example, for decap-cms on SO, there's synonym "netlify-cms" listed in related tags:



More over, if you tap on it you'll see doubled [decap-cms] in search bar and "tagged with" section:



There's a similar issue with current tag as well: Current Tag included under Related Tags
